# Hyperlink only shows on the bottom of textview, not in the middle

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink

I am making an application voor Android, using Java in Eclipse. I am using buttons with in each one, some information text. Along with the text, I make use of hyperlinks that lead to a website. However, when I try to place my hyperlink after the second sentance, it automatically places it after the last sentence. in `strings.xml` I can place the link at the beginning, middle or somehwere in between that, but in the actual come out, the link will be at the very end.

I have an image to show where the link is positioned, (at the end of the textview) and my strings.xml code to show you that the link is coded in the middle of the textview.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

This is the image that shows the textview, along with the hyperlink at the end of it.

[image: Click here to see the image]

This is my `strings.xml` code for that page on the image:

```
<string name="title_activity_nieuws"><b>Nieuws</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Agenda</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; Voorlichtingsbijeenkomsten, symposia, open dagen en andere evenementen die het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis organiseert vindt u in de Agenda op onze website (een internetverbinding is nodig).</a>
</string>
```

Main code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NieuwsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nieuws);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_nieuws);
        text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> Naar het nieuwsoverzicht </a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {


            case R.id.button11:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                intent = new Intent(NieuwsActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code where u r setting this text in your textview

Comment: added the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to show text link above "Agenda"

Firstly, you should change the your string to:

```
<string
name="title_activity_nieuws"><![CDATA[Nieuws<br/>Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <br/><br/><a href=\'https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws\'>Naar het nieuwsoverzicht</a> <br/><br/>Agenda<br/><br/> Voorlichtingsbijeenkomsten, symposia, open dagen en andere evenementen die het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis organiseert vindt u in de Agenda op onze website (een internetverbinding is nodig).]]></string>
```

Secondly, comment-out line:

```
text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> Naar het nieuwsoverzicht </a>";
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you sir, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the below line

```
 text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> Naar het nieuwsoverzicht </a>";
```

Change your `title_activity_nieuws` string

The placement of `</a>` is incorrect

```
<string name="title_activity_nieuws"><b>Nieuws</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</a><b>Agenda</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; Voorlichtingsbijeenkomsten, symposia, open dagen en andere evenementen die het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis organiseert vindt u in de Agenda op onze website (een internetverbinding is nodig).
```

Comment: Now the link is just gone. Doesn't show anything in my textview now

Comment: That's literally what I have in my code, what do I need to change?

Comment: Your closing hyperlink tag  '</a>' is misplaced.Please correct it

Comment: Use - <string
name="title_activity_nieuws"><![CDATA[Nieuws<br/>Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <br/><br/><a href=\'https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws\'>Naar het nieuwsoverzicht</a> <br/><br/>Agenda<br/><br/> Voorlichtingsbijeenkomsten, symposia, open dagen en andere evenementen die het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis organiseert vindt u in de Agenda op onze website (een internetverbinding is nodig).]]></string>